# Optimizing Java Regex Matching

Tags: java, regex

I'm using an application that takes udp packets containing logs from a game server and uses them to glean information on what is going on with the server - it does this via regex matching. However, I'm running into an issue that if the program is receiving enough packets at once the cpu usage goes up quiet a bit - after looking at a thread dump this appears to be due to the regex matching..

Here's an example of two of the patterns:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*World triggered \"Game_Over\" reason \"(.+)\"");
Pattern chatPattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.+)<([0-9]+)><\\[(U:[0-9]:[0-9]+)\\]><(Blue|Red)>\" say \"(.+)\"");
```

Then it creates a matcher based on said patterns and the log line it is given and checks matches. It does this for 5 different patterns each time it recieves a packet - How can I optimize this to lower the cpu usage?

Comment: add a `+` after all `+`'s inorder to avoid backtracking.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - please explain.  How / why does that avoid backtracking?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I optimize this to lower the cpu usage?

1. Make sure that you don't repeatedly "compile" the same pattern; i.e. compile each one once, and cache it.
2. Refactor the patterns so that if there are common (meta-)patterns you can avoid repeated matching.
3. Refactor so that the initial match can be done using `String.indexOf()`.  For example, in the first one you could use `indexOf` to search for "World triggered".  Then use the regex *starting at the initial match offset* to confirm the match.
4. Don't use regexes at all.  Hard code the searches.

---

But before you go down this path you should *profile* the application to confirm your belief that you have a performance problem, AND that the pattern matching is *really* a significant performance bottleneck.